# Hibernate multiple query execution on jsp page load

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

Dear Fellow Developers,

I have a JSP page Which has a form. When you fill up the form and click the save button the JSP will call the servlet and servlet will call the JAVA DAO File(Responsible for all hibernate operation) to save the data in database(MySQL).
After successful insertion the user can not see the fill up page again. User can only see the edit page using a link. So if user try to navigate to form again it will take them to the link for edit(Because data is already stored in the database). Now user can edit or update the data. The problem which i am facing is When user click on the link (Edit Info) it will take them to the edit page, data will be retrieved using hibernate and will be displayed on JSP page. Every time user will click on Edit link In background or console i can see hibernate select query  execution multiple times. Why is it happening i don't have any idea. So if i load the edit page using the link the select query should execute only once but is executing multiple times(sometimes 10 sometimes 20 25 15 etc.)
Please share the knowledge and let me know why it is happening. Its a dynamic web project. Latest Hibernate version.

Comment: can you post your code... It would help to investigate further

Comment: I can post the code in your email. share your email with me so i can send you the code

Comment: you can post the code here in Stackoverflow. This way knowledge can be shared. However you can send me at sidharthdash19@gmail.com

Comment: check your mail plz

Comment: I got it. will come back to you